# How do I read data from a Google Docs Spreadsheet Using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, google-docs

I have working found examples of writing to a Google Docs spreadsheet using JavaScript/jQuery (which I would have thought would have been the harder part).

However, I am struggling to find any current examples of searching a Docs spreadsheet for rows whose cells have matching criteria and returning those rows using jQuery.   The few that I have found are all pointing to ancient Google API documents.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Google Apps Script? Here is a link with some documentation on how to connect to a Google Spreadsheet for the purpose of parsing its data: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.